# How to Sort value in datagridview in c# WinForms?

Tags: c#, sorting, datagridview

if i input `jam` in the `datagridview` 
it will appear on the first row.

```
if i enter another value like `jom` it will do the same.

jom
jam
jjim
jum
jem
```

i do like this

```
Select * from CompanyInfo ORDER By CompanyName
```

Comment: what is the question? and what have you tried?

Comment: call the sort method on datagridview. you have to implement Icomparer interface for this method.

Answer (score 0):

```
Select * from CompanyInfo ORDER By Date DESC
```

Date is the modifier so that if you enter a value the cuurrent date will on the top. :) thats how i did to my codes :3